# Google DFP: set custom data and reuse them with javascript

Tags: google-dfp

Is possible to set custom data on a DFP ad creative, in the console panel, and then reuse them on the front end of your web site?

For example let say I have an ad, that have a list of creatives. 
Depending on the creative it is displaying, which has a **custom field** with a **number**. With javascript I want to read this **number** on my web page, and do different actions depending on (change title of document or activate an app related to the DFP).

More over is possible to display in an Ad a custom js application (ex. a calculator) which the user can interact with it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find a way to extract creative's custom fields via javascript. Most likely it's not exposed on the page because it's been designed for a slightly different purpose:

> These optional fields can be used to organize objects in reports. They're created in the "Admin" tab. They don't affect ad serving or delivery

But you can do it differently in a number of ways:

1. bind to creative IDs - if a particular creative id is shown do some actions of your choice. These IDs are available in your DFP 'creatives' grid.
2. if you're not limited to image creatives you can use 3rd party creatives with a js code that would communicate to the parent page and pass some data to your js handler installed on the parent page. As DFP uses friendly iframes (http://www.iab.net/media/file/rich_media_ajax_best_practices.pdf) you do have access to the parent page from inside your ad
3. A dirtier approach - you can put some service data into the **alt** field which is reachable inside the ad from the parent page
4. There's also an attribute event.[labelIds](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.ResponseInformation_labelIds) available in the event handler but it's empty despite some labels associated with my testing creative

Here's the code illustrating p.1 and p.3:

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {    
    if (!event.isEmpty) {                                                   
        var slotId = event.slot.getSlotElementId();                         
        var iframe = document.querySelector('#' + slotId + ' iframe');      
        var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
        var img = iframeDoc.querySelector('img');                           
        if (img && img.alt) {                                               
            console.log('Got alt: ' + img.alt);                             
        }                                                                   
        if (event.creativeId) {                                             
            console.log('Got creative id: ' + event.creativeId);            
        }                                                                   
    }                                                                       
});
```

Here it is live: https://jsfiddle.net/50b4npw8/

You can find some additional info on GPT events [here](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent)